# UIImagePicker Adjusting Focus Observer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, avfoundation

Is there a way to find out if the camera is currently focusing with UIImagePicker?  Similar to the way the adjustingFocus observer works with AVFoundation.

I'm currently using AVFoundation, but I would like to be able to have the image quality that is achieved with UIImagePicker.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your exact requirement here - what is that you want adjusting focus observer for? As the name suggests, it is a way to signal you that `AVCaptureDevice` (reference to "real" device - one of [these devices](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009539-CH4g-SW223)) is adjusting its focus. `UIImagePicker` is nothing but a file open dialog, not a real device. It works on top of either camera or static list of image files. While in camera mode, you can observe adjustingFocus.

In case that is your requirement, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9110038/1506363) is nearest you can refer to. 
Refer to [UIImagePickerController documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) to define how you can implement this for your own needs.