# Key-Value Observing adjustingFocus no notification

Tags: objective-c, camera, ios9, key-value-observing

I'm not familiar with iOS but I'm trying to find when the default, built-in camera application is focusing. To do this I create my own separate Objective-C application and following this answer here [[iPhone : camera autofocus observer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9100357/iphone-camera-autofocus-observer][1]) but I'm not getting anything from observeValueForKeyPath in the NSLog.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "AVFoundation/AVCaptureDevice.h"
#import "AVFoundation/AVMediaFormat.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSLog(@"viewDidLoad");
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// callback
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    NSLog(@"observeValueForKeyPath");
    if( [keyPath isEqualToString:@"adjustingFocus"] ){
        BOOL adjustingFocus = [ [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] ];
        NSLog(@"Is adjusting focus? %@", adjustingFocus ? @"YES" : @"NO" );
        NSLog(@"Change dictionary: %@", change);
    }
    if( [keyPath isEqualToString:@"focusMode"] ){
        AVCaptureFocusMode focusMode = [ [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] ];
        NSLog(@"focusMode? %ld", focusMode);
    }
}

// register observer
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear: animated];
    NSLog(@"viewWillAppear");
    AVCaptureDevice *camDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    int flags = NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew;
    [camDevice addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"adjustingFocus" options:flags context:nil];
    [camDevice addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"focusMode" options:flags context:nil];
}

@end
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Can you able to the live camera preview on your view controller? As per the code you provided, it looks like you just creating `AVCaptureDevice` instance and doing nothing with that.

Comment: @Bluewings I'd like to observe the adjustingFocus key/value when the camera is being used by the native iPhone camera application, so I am not creating a preview in my own code. Can we use KVO to observe keys from other applications?

Comment: Nope you can not observe from other applications. As per the documentation you have to get a lock for using any AVCaptureDevice to use or manipulate it. So when other application is using any capture device you can not actually get to know about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who visits this question, the answer is what Bluewings wrote as a comment. I was trying to use KVO to observe one application from another which is not possible since only one lock on a capture device is possible at one time.